# Opacity of 3D models and meshes in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx-8

Is it possible to change meshes opacity in JavaFX 8? I've tried to use `setOpacity()` and `opacityProperty()` of `MeshView` but it seems there is no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparency/opacity support is still under development and will not be available in the first GA-release in 03/2014. See issues [RT-28874](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28874) and [RT-34356](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-34356).